# How we can put a break on Intent (Dialogflow)

Tags: dialogflow-es

Do someone know how to put a break on an intent, 
example, when the TEXT response says: Hello John`***...Break of 5sc...***` How can I help you ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow supports [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) in text responses, which support a `<break>` element. It does not say what the maximum duration of a break is, but I doubt it will be more than a few second.